# HTSeq - NameError: name 're' is not defined

Tags: nameerror

I'm trying to use HTSeq but I'm getting "NameError: name 're' is not defined" after import HTSeq command.
As I'm a novice, I don't know how to resolve the issue. It would be nice if someone could help me in getting through.

```
import HTSeq
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
import HTSeq
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\HTSeq\__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
_re_attr_main = re.compile( "\s*([^\s\=]+)[\s=]+(.*)" )
NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

Comment: Attempt to improve formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You must `import re` at the beginning of your program to import the `re` module.